# meaning of indecipherable part of a novel

Tags: meaning

> “I ain’t a beggar, marm, an’ I don’t want nothin’ o’ you. I was
>   **cal’latin’** ter work, of course, fur my board an’ keep. I wouldn’t have
>   come ter your old house, anyhow, if this ‘ere girl hadn’t ’a’ made me,
>   a-tellin’ me how you was so good an’ kind that you’d be jest dyin’ ter
>   take me in. So, there!” And he wheeled about and stalked from the room
>   **with a dignity that would have been absurd had it not been so pitiful.**

The quote above is from  Eleanor Porter’s *[Pollyanna](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/1450)*, published in 1913.
It is hard for me to catch the meaning of the emphasized parts.

Comment: **calculating**?

Comment: To **call at**? (calling at X, to work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**cal'latin'** is the -ing form of *[cal'late](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cal%27late).*

As the reference says, *cal'late* is a variant of *[calculate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/calculate).*  Just how often cal'late is used nowadays is a mystery to me, but I expect it is an old form. The general meaning of the phrase *cal'latin' ter work* is *planning or intending to work.*

Nine other examples of cal'latin (all not so modern) can be found [here on wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/cal%27latin). In all the examples, it is close to meaning  *planning.*

You can also look up *cal'late* on wordnik. Most of these examples mean *suppose* or *reckon.*

As for

> And he wheeled about and stalked from the room **with a dignity that would have been absurd had it not been so pitiful**,

this is straightforward:

He turned around and left the room in **a dignified manner that could be described as absurd if it had not been so pitiful**.

Comment: I learn new (old) words everyday, and I'm cal'latin' on usin' 'em someday!